# Integral of multivariate gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution, integral

I'm calculating a posteriori distribution, which is solving this integral:
$$
\int d^Jx \frac{\exp \left[\left( \vec{x}^\intercal \Omega^{-1} \vec{x} \right)/2\right]}{(2\pi)^{J/2}\sqrt{|\Omega|}} 
\frac{\exp \left[\left(r - a \vec{D}\cdot\vec{x} \right)^2 / 2(1-a^2)\right]}{\sqrt{2\pi(1-a^2)}}
$$

$\vec{D}$ is a vector of size $J$, so $\vec{D}\cdot\vec{x}$ is a scalar.
I should be able to use the fact that they are two multivariate gaussians, but actually the second is not, so I am not sure on how to approach this one in a simple way.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what the "second" is and why you think it's not Gaussian?  After applying basic laws of exponentiation, all I see here are constants (which you can factor out) times the exponential of a quadratic form in $x:$ and that's *exactly* what "Gaussian" means.

Comment: I meant that is not multivariate, since Dx is a scalar, so I don't know how to write it in a quadratic form

Comment: It *is* multivariate.  Write out the arguments of the exponentials for the case $J=2,$ using specific values of $\Omega^{-1}$ (try the identity matrix), $D$ (use something simple like $D=(1,2)$), and $r$ ($r=0$ will do for a start).  Set $a=0$ for simplicity.  To evaluate the integral, [complete the square](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=complet*+the+square).

Comment: The case $a=0$ is trivial. In the case $r=0$ then is clear that I can say that the second distribution is multivariate with inverse covariance matrix $a^2\vec{D}\vec{D}^\intercal/(1-a^2)$. What I need to understand is how this changes when I shift the center of this distribution with $r$. In other words, what is $\mu$ of the second distribution

Comment: The case $a\ne 0,$ then, is equally trivial, because all it does is introduce a constant multiplier and a scalar times a quadratic form is a quadratic form.  The shift of the center is *precisely* what is computed by completing the square; and after you have done that, it tells you how to transform the variable to eliminate all but the purely quadratic terms in the exponentials.  Thus, a full answer to your question is "complete the square."